# Formatting equation numbers in endnotes

Tags: equations, numbering, endnotes

I want to insert some equations in my endnotes at the end of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{endnotes} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\def\footnotetext{\endnotetext[\number+1]}
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark 
\def\enoteheading{\par\kern2\baselineskip%
                  \footnoterule%
                  \kern1\baselineskip}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chap 1}

Hello\endnote{
\begin{equation}
z = x + y
\end{equation}}

\begin{equation}
A = B \sin(x)
\end{equation}

\chapter{chap 2}

\begin{equation}
C = D \cos(x)
\end{equation}

\appendix
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

I want these equations in the `endnote` environment to be in the Appendix section and for equation numbering to start at `A.1`, `A.2` etc. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's done by default, provided you use the correct markup for the start.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{endnotes} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter{Notes}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chap 1}

Hello\endnote{Let's state an equation
\begin{equation}
z = x + y
\end{equation}}

\begin{equation}
A = B \sin(x)
\end{equation}

\chapter{chap 2}

\begin{equation}
C = D \cos(x)
\end{equation}

\appendix
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]